# Object gets faster after each bounce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a simple collision script because the unity collision option isn't flexible enough for my needs.
CollDetect is on each bullet (objects with trigger collider) and I want it to bounce on some surfaces. I wrote here a bouncing script but when I run it, the object gets faster after each bounce. Also, when I remove the gravity code, everything works fine, no speed increase.

```cs
var velocity = speed * transform.right;
var collDetect = bullet.GetComponent<CollisionDetect>();
var bulletTransf = bullet.transform;
bulletTransf.position = transform.position;

collDetect.OnTriggerEnter += coll =>
{
    if (coll.gameObject.layer != environmentLayer) return;

    var collisionPoints = collDetect.Colliders
        .Where(c=>c.gameObject.layer == environmentLayer)
        .Select(c=>c.ClosestPoint(bulletTransf.position))
        .ToArray();

    var collisionNormal = ((Vector2)bulletTransf.position - collisionPoints[0]).normalized;
    var bounceVector = Vector2.Reflect(velocity, collisionNormal);
    velocity = bounceVector;

    // idk why it gets faster          
};

collDetect.OnObjDisable += collDtct =>
{
    collDetect.MyCollider.isTrigger = true;

    collDtct.EmptyOnTriggerEnter();
    collDtct.EmptyOnTriggerExit();
    collDtct.EmptyOnObjDisable();
};

while (true)
{
    bulletTransf.position += velocity;

    // Maybe I wrote the gravity code incorrectly
    if (velocity.y > -gravityIntensity)
        velocity += gravityIntensity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Vector3.down;

    yield return fixedUpdate;
}
```

Why is it happening? I wanted to try to add a dampening value but I figured that would be a bandaid solution

Comment: change your gravity code to this `if (Math.abs(velocity.y) > gravityIntensity)`

Comment: Math.abs is the absolute value of whatever is passed in

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen That would clamp the gravity even if the "y" value is positive, no?

Comment: you are correct @Stefan